# ImageJ - Running concatenate from a macro - valid choice error

Tags: java, image, image-processing, imagej

I am trying to run concatenation of two images through a macro. The final aim is to use in a batch mode.

Here is the code:

```
dir1 = getDirectory("Choose Source Directory ");

list = getFileList(dir1);

i=0;
filename1 = dir1 + list[i];
filename2 = dir1 + list[i+1];

open(filename1);
open(filename2);

imag1 = list[i]; imag2 = list[i+1];

run("Concatenate...", "  title=[Concatenated Stacks] image1=imag1 image2=imag2");
```

When executed, the error is like this:

[image]

What is the right *choice* for executing this macro?

Answer (score 1):

(**Note**: ImageJ usage questions are best asked on the [ImageJ forum](http://forum.imagej.net/) instead of here.)

You're currently setting the input to a literal "imag1", and there is no opened image with the title "imag1". You have to provide the **content** of your variable to the option string of the Concatenate command, either by string concatenation, or with the ImageJ-specific `&variable` syntax.

---

From the ImageJ1 [Macro Language documentation](https://imagej.net/developer/macro/macros.html#run):

> The input fields of a dialog can be set to the contents of a macro variables by using string concatentation:
>
> ```
> noise = 50;
> output = "Point Selection";
> run("Find Maxima...", "noise="+noise+" output=["+output+"] light");
> ```
>
> With ImageJ 1.43 and later, there is an easier method that only requires adding "&" to the variable name in the options string:
>
> ```
> noise = 50;
> output = "Point Selection";
> run("Find Maxima...", "noise=&noise output=&output light");
> ```